# Issue Eclipse helio 3.6 with GWT Plugin

Tags: gwt, eclipse-3.6

I have installed GWT plugin with eclipse helio 3.6 , after installation i have restarted eclipse, I was found the google plugin in installed software list., but I cannot see any of the plugin's toolbar icons in the eclipse IDE. Please any one give me the suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem now. I have downloaded new eclipse-helio 3.6 and tried it. It was works now.